# Segment to polyline matching python or GIS

Tags: python, gps, gis

I have a series of GPS points which collectively form a polyline. Each of these GPS points has a time stamp and I can therefore compute things like journey time and average speed along the poly line.

I now wish to map the resulting polyline onto a road network. However, for obvious reasons the GPS points don't line up with the actual infrastructure and I must attempt to match them across. Is there a python library for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `pyproj`, `geopandas`, and `rtree`.

Comment: Can you explain rtree? I can't understand what I'd use this for

Comment: It is essentially an algorithm that makes user defined squares to then test if points fall within those coordinates. It can also do other things besides that.